# Easily install Android Application from computer?

Tags: android, installation, apk

A client is releasing a product (employee training/guide), and have contracted us to create a companion application for the Android OS.

Being a global entity that routinely has employees in areas without network access, they are releasing their product via CD.

They would like the ability for their users to optionally install this companion application to their personal Android devices (their own cell phones/tablets etc).

Since some will be in areas without network/internet access, they would really like the ability for an installer to be on this CD to install the Android application.

I am somewhat familiar with being able to install applications onto Android using ADB, but was under the impression this would require root.

Is there a method by which an application could be installed from a computer, in such a way that a non-tech savvy user could use it (IE classic installer application, just different target).

Don't want to be asking these people to root their devices, install ADB and so forth.

Comment: adb does not require root, but it does require that the user turn on usb debugging in settings and that the computer being used have appropriate usb drivers for the phone and enough of the sdk to run adb, or alternate functionality such as the sideload wonder machine.

Comment: Sounds like you just need wait a bit when Android releases the update to Market. http://www.net-security.org/article.php?id=1556

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am somewhat familiar with being able to install applications onto Android using ADB, but was under the impression this would require root.

No.

> Is there a method by which an application could be installed from a computer, in such a way that a non-tech savvy user could use it (IE classic installer application, just different target).

There is the [Sideload Wonder Machine](http://www.androidcentral.com/sideload-android-apps-all-you-want-sideload-wonder-machine), but I haven't tried it, and it is Windows-specific. It also would still require adb-compatible drivers, which the user may or may not have installed on their Windows machine.

Otherwise, there are no network-less options at this time that I am aware of.

Comment: Aha thanks, this will work. Looks like it's open source too, so we can modify it to create an installer package. We'll just see about the possibility of bundling installers for ADB drivers for the most common devices, or refer them to links if not legally viable to bundle drivers.

Answer (score 3):

I think the ADB route is asking for trouble as you're reliant on the right drivers being present on the machine. Sometimes it'll work fine, sometimes it won't.

You could potentially provide the APK on an SD card for the phone, but there's no consistent app to use to open the APK from the phone, so that's unlikely to be any better.

Surely if they are using phones they do SOMETIMES have network access? I suspect you're going to struggle to find a nice solution, and although not ideal maybe better to just require that users install the app when they do get a connection?

Going down that route, you could provide the APK via email, a web link, Android Market, or any alternative market.

Do remember that the cost of a solution isn't just building it, but the support too. My sense is when you're looking at the possibility you might have to help users install the right driver, you need to look for a better solution as that's the road to hell.

Comment: Yeah, it seems odd to me that lots of people would have Android phones without any network access.  What good is an Android phone if you can't get email, maps, etc?

Comment: you could also probably make a windows installer packaging the adb driver from the SDK, you android app and an install script.

Comment: @Stephane - not really as the drivers will sometimes differ between devices

Comment: The end client is a military based organization. They don't always know where they'll get deployed, or what network services will be available for their personal devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is still another option that nobody mentioned, which does not involve dealing with USB drivers. BTW, this is only a Windows problem, in most Linux distros ADB works out-of-the-box.
This option is through WiFi:

1. configure Tethering & portable hotspot
2. connect the computer to the hotspot
3. start some kind of web server on the computer (apache will do, probably [microapache](http://microapache.kerys.co.uk/) could be of help if using Windows)
4. on the phone open the URL containing the APK (the IP was given by the hotspot)
5. download
6. install
7. Voila !